# Why is the restriction of being "Monic " is imposed on the divisor element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

I'm reading the following proof,upto now i'd read division algorithm only for $\mathbb F[x],$where $\mathbb F$ is field.In this proof i first time encountered with the notion of division algorithm in $\mathbb Z[x]$,where $\mathbb Z$ is a set of integers(integral domain).

I've two queries regarding the following proof-

[image]

- Why is the restriction of being "Monic " is imposed on the divisor
  element?
- Where does the division algorithm fail if above restriction is removed?

Here is the main source https://brilliant.org/wiki/cyclotomic-polynomials/

Comment: Have you tried a few cases? Such as $f(X)=1$, $g(X)=2$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician:I've tried .I wanted to know via some analytic argument why divisor has to be monic.

Comment: I've given you an example to show that some restriction is necessary. Surely if long division is going to "work" the leading coecfficient of the divisor has to divide the leading coefficients otherwise we'll not knock the degree down each step. Asking for the leading coefficient of the divisor to be $1$ (or better, to be a unit) is just right.

Comment: @ancientmathematician:Thank you,i thought of the same but unable to express it....

Answer (score 1):

The divisor has to be monic, because otherwise the result is not necessarily true. It is easy to find two polynomials $f, g$ in ${\mathbb Z}[x]$ such that $g | f$ in ${\mathbb C}[x]$ but whose quotient $f/g$ is *not* in ${\mathbb Z}[x]$. For instance, as @ancientmathematician mentions in a comment, $f = 1$ and $g = 2$.

The normal division algorithm cancels the highest term of $f$ by subtracting a suitable multiple of $g$ (and then repeating this until the degree of $f$ drops below the degree of $g$). This *suitable multiple* is $(\text{lc}(f) / \text{lc}(g)) g$. If $\text{lc}(g) = 1$ (or $-1$), this is guaranteed to be in ${\mathbb Z}[x]$.